# \FPsignpol command from esami LaTeX package

Tags: spacing, esami

The LaTeX package `esami` lets you prepare exams with some ease. The command `\FPsignpol` defined below is used to write polynomial coefficients depending on parameters. It is bases on the command `\FPval` from the `\fp` package.

```
{\FPval\tempsign{#1}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{\ifnum \tempsign<0 {\sempli{\tempsign}{1}#2}\else \ifnum \tempsign>0{+\sempli{\tempsign}{1}#2}\else{}\fi\fi}
{\ifnum \tempsign<0 {\semplix{\tempsign}{1}#2}\else \ifnum \tempsign>0{+\semplix{\tempsign}{1}#2}\else{}\fi\fi}
}
```

However when computing coefficients, the plus/minus sign is too near to the number. The modified version `\FPsignpoli` defined below improves the space between the plus sign and the numbers in case of positive coefficients, but I cannot figure out how to do for negative ones.

```
{\FPval\tempsign{#1}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{\ifnum \tempsign<0 {\,\sempli{\tempsign}{1}#2}\else \ifnum \tempsign>0{\,+\,\sempli{\tempsign}{1}#2}\else{}\fi\fi}
{\ifnum \tempsign<0 {\semplix{\tempsign}{1}#2}\else \ifnum \tempsign>0{\,+\,\semplix{\tempsign}{1}#2}\else{}\fi\fi}
}
```

The following picture provides examples for both outputs.

[image]

Could you please help me in solving the issue. Thank you in advance.

Here is a complete example, 3 files needed: master.tex, esami-xyz.cfg and the file ex.tex of the only exercise included in this example.

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX root = master3DM-1IQ-2021-22.tex

\documentclass[italian,a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[text={1550mm,250mm},centering]{geometry}
%\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=4.1cm,right=2.1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[shuffle,xyz,autopstoff,solutions]{esami}%%%%% TEMA

\geometry{a4paper,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=1.1cm,right=1.1cm}

\usepackage{float,tikz}

\def\profname{Professor Name}
\def\examname{Data}
\def\numcompiti{1}%%% The number of versions
\date{2021/10/09}%%% THE DATE IN THE FORMAT AAAA/M/D
\def\Data{\longdate}%%% or \shortdate: the date in the heading

\begin{document}
\testversioni
%\pagestyle{esame}
\pagestyle{empty}

\whiledo{\thevers<\numcompiti}{\stepvers
% +=============================+
% |       THE SEED              |
% +=============================+
%\FPeval\seme{round((\thenomefile+(3*\thevers)):0)}
%% OR OTHER SUCH AS
\FPeval\seme{round(\thenomefile*(\thevers)+1-trunc(\thenomefile*(\thevers)/(2^31-1):0)*(2^31-1):0)}
%\FPeval\seme{round(1+abs(\thenomefile/(\thevers)+sin(\thevers)*(\thevers)^(2)):0)}

\randomi=\seme

% +=============================+
% |  STUFF DEFINED IN CFG FILE  |
% +=============================+

%\testa%%% the heading
%\istruzionii%%%  some instructions


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\renewcommand\exlabelformat{{\scshape\exlabel}}



\begin{center}
{\Large \textsc{School name}
\\~\\
\textsc{Test name}}
\\
\end{center}

\esercizi{ex}



\vskip0.5cm
\hrule

\setcounter{ex@no}{0}

\closevers
}
\end{document}
```

```
%% Package `esami' to use with LaTeX 2e
%%  Copyright (C) 2008-2013  G. Messineo e S. Vassallo
%%
%% This is file `esami-xyz.cfg',
%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% esami-xyz.cfg,             2013-03-20                %%
%% Copyright (C) 2008-2013 G. Messineo e S. Vassallo    %%
%%                                                      %%
%% This program can be redistributed and/or modified    %%
%% under the terms of the LaTeX Project Public License  %%
%% Distributed from CTAN archives in directory          %%
%% macros/latex/base/lppl.txt; either version 1 of the  %%
%% License, or (at your option) any later version.      %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% +=============================+
% |         THE HEADING         |
% +=============================+

 \@ifpackagewith{esami}{prova}{%
 \def\testa{\relax}}
{%
\def\testa{
\setcounter{page}{0}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
~\vskip3cm
{\huge \hskip1cm\textsc{School name}}
\vskip0.8cm
{\huge\hskip1cm\textsc{Test name}}
\vskip0.8cm
{\huge\hskip1cm\textsc{del \underline{~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}}
}
\end{center}
\vskip0.5cm 

\noindent
\hskip1cm \underline{\textsc{Studente name}: 
\hskip6cm \textsc{Class}: ~~~}%
\vskip0.7mm
\vskip1cm


\vfill\eject

\vskip1cm
\vfill\eject
%   {\bfseries\sffamily\small
%   \begin{center}
%   \begin{tabular}{|lp{.33\textwidth}|lp{.33\textwidth}|lp{.33\textwidth}|}
%   \hline
%   \multicolumn{1}{|p{.33\textwidth}}{\profname }&\multicolumn{1}{|p{.33\textwidth}}   {\examname  } &\multicolumn{1}{|p{.34\textwidth}|}{Classe}\\[3ex]
%   \hline
%   \multicolumn{1}{|p{.33\textwidth}}{Cognome (in stampatello)}&\multicolumn{1}{|p{.   33\textwidth}}{Nome (in stampatello)}&\multicolumn{1}{|p{.34\textwidth}|}{Firma     leggibile}\\[4ex]
%   \hline
%   \end{tabular}\\[3ex]
%   \end{center}}
 }
 }

% +=============================+
% |         THE FOOTER          |
% +=============================+

\ifes@solutions%%%solutions
\def\ps@esame{\let\@oddhead\@empty\def\@oddfoot{\hfil \textbf{\versionname\
n. \thevers} -- %%
\textbf{\solutionsname} --  %%
 \pagename\ \thepage  \hfill  Alunna/o \underline{~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~} Classe 3A
\hfil}\let\@evenhead\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty}
\else%%% no solutions
    \def\ps@esame{
    \let\@oddhead\@empty\def\@oddfoot%%
    {\hfil  \textbf{\versionname\ n. \thevers\
      -- \pagename\ \thepage  \hfill Alunna/o \underline{~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~} Classe 3A}\hfil}
\let\@evenhead\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty}
\fi

% +=============================+
% |   THE SOLUTION STRING       |
% +=============================+

\def\ps@soltest{\let\@oddhead\@empty\def\@oddfoot{\hfil %\textbf{\versionname\ n. \thevers} -- %%
\textbf{\solutionsname} -- \pagename\ \thepage
\hfil}\let\@evenhead\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty}

\ifes@solutions
\newcommand{\stringasol}{\newpage%
\vspace{.8cm}
\pagestyle{soltest}
 \input{\jobname.sol.tex}                                                                                %
}
\else
\newcommand{\stringasol}{\relax}
\fi


% +=============================+
% |   SOME INTRUCTIONS          |
% +=============================+

\def\istruzionii{{
\sffamily \textbf{ISTRUZIONI}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Il punteggio per chi consegna in bianco \`e di punti 1 su 10.
  \item Non \`e consentito consegnare altri fogli oltre alla presente scheda
  \item La durata della prova \`e di un’ora.
  \item Firmare ogni foglio.
\end{itemize}}}

\def\istruzioniii{\setlength{\fboxsep}{1.5ex}\setlength{\fboxrule}{1.2pt}{\sffamily
\framebox{\parbox{\textwidth}{\textbf{Some other instructions.}}}}\\[3ex]}
```

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX root = master3DM-1IQ-2021-22.tex

\newproblem{
\FPsetpar{a}{-13}{-3}


\begin{problem}\PTs{2} Dato il polinomio
$$
-2x^3 \FPsignpol{-4*\a+7}{x^2}\FPsignpol{-2*\a*\a+11*\a-4}{x}\FPsignpol{4*\a*\a-6*\a-4}{}
$$
$$
-2x^3 \FPsignpoli{-4*\a+7}{x^2}\FPsignpoli{-2*\a*\a+11*\a-4}{x}\FPsignpoli{4*\a*\a-6*\a-4}{}
$$
\begin{itemize}
\item[2.1]\PTs{1,25} Studiane il segno.
\item[2.2]\PTs{0,25} Indica per quali valori di $x$ il polinomio dato non si annulla;
\item[2.3]\PTs{0,25} Indica per quali valori di $x$ il polinomio dato è positivo;
\item[2.4]\PTs{0,25} Indica per quali valori di $x$ il polinomio dato è negativo.
\end{itemize}
\textit{Suggerimento: dividi il polinomio per $(x-2)$.}
\begin{solution}
Dopo aver diviso il polinomio dato per $(x-2)$, si ottiene che
$$
-2x^3 \FPsignpol{-4*\a+7}{x^2}\FPsignpol{-2*\a*\a+11*\a-4}{x}\FPsignpol{4*\a*\a-6*\a-4}{}
=
(x-2)(-2x^2\FPsignpol{-4*\a+3}{x}\FPsignpol{-2*\a*\a+3*\a+2}{})
$$
l'ultimo fattore di secondo grado ha, a sua volta, due radici: $\displaystyle\sempliz{-2*\a-1}{2}$ e $\FPsv{2-\a}$, pertanto il segno del polinomio dato scaturisce da quello dei due fattori trovati:
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (0,0)-- (8,0) node[above,right]{$x$};
\draw (2,-3) -- (2,0) node[above]{$2$};
\draw (4,-3) -- (4,0) node[above]{$\displaystyle\sempliz{-2*\a-1}{2}$};
\draw (6,-3) -- (6,0) node[above]{$\FPsv{2-\a}$};
\draw (-0.5,-1) node[left]{$x-2$};
\draw (0,-1)--(2,-1) node[fill=white]{$0$};
\draw[dashed] (2.2,-1)--(8,-1);
\draw (-0.5,-2) node[left]{$-2x^2\FPsignpol{-4*\a+3}{x}\FPsignpol{-2*\a*\a+3*\a+2}{}$};
\draw (0,-2) -- (4,-2) node[fill=white]{$0$};
\draw[dashed] (4.2,-2)--(6,-2) node[fill=white]{$0$};
\draw (6.2,-2) -- (8,-2);
\draw (-0.5,-3) node[left]{$-2x^3 \FPsignpol{-4*\a+7}{x^2}\FPsignpol{-2*\a*\a+11*\a-4}{x}\FPsignpol{4*\a*\a-6*\a-4}{}$};
\draw (0,-3)--(2,-3) node[below]{$0$};
\draw[dashed] (2,-3)--(4,-3) node[below]{$0$};
\draw (4,-3)--(6,-3) node[below]{$0$};
\draw[dashed] (6,-3)--(8,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
Questo grafico conclude lo studio richiesto nel quesito 2.1. 
Pertanto, 
\begin{itemize}
\item[2.2] il polinomio non si annulla per $x\neq 2\;\wedge \;x\neq\displaystyle\sempliz{-2*\a-1}{2}\;\wedge\;x\neq \FPsv{2-\a}$;
\item[2.3] il polinomio è positivo per $x<2\;\vee\;\displaystyle\sempliz{-2*\a-1}{2}<x<\FPsv{2-\a}$;
\item[2.4] il polinomio è negativo per $2<x<\displaystyle\sempliz{-2*\a-1}{2}\;\vee\; x>\FPsv{2-\a}$.
\end{itemize}


(Il valore del parametro è $\a$)
\end{solution}
\end{problem}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example that shows your use-case for the final examples? Your code should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. Can you do that?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I have just edited the question with a complete example

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `FPsignpol` or `\FPsignpoli`, use the `\printcoeff` where

```
\usepackage{xfp}
\newcommand{\printcoeff}[1]{%
  \ifnum\inteval{#1}<0
    \inteval{#1}%
  \else
    +\inteval{#1}%
  \fi
}
```

Here's the difference:

[image]

```
\[
  -2x^3 \FPsignpol{-4*\a+7}{x^2}\FPsignpol{-2*\a*\a+11*\a-4}{x}\FPsignpol{4*\a*\a-6*\a-4}{}
\]
\[
  -2x^3 \printcoeff{-4*\a+7}x^2 \printcoeff{-2*\a*\a+11*\a-4}x \printcoeff{4*\a*\a-6*\a-4}
\]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The macro `\FPval` of the `esami` package is not completely equal to the macro `\FPeval` of the `FP` package, as it allows to print the parametric version of the expression inserted if the `param` option is specified (otherwise it calculates the result). So, to achieve the better spacing required, both in the numeric and in the parametric version, you can use this slighly modified definition of the `\FPsignpol` macro:

```
    \newcommand{\FPsignpol}[2]{\FPval\tempsign{#1}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{\ifnum \tempsign<0 {\:\sempli{\tempsign}                               
    {1}#2}\else \ifnum \tempsign>0{\:+\:\sempli{\tempsign}{1}#2}\else{}
    \fi\fi}
    {\ifnum \tempsign<0 {\:\semplix{\tempsign}{1}#2\:}\else \ifnum 
    \tempsign>0{\:+\:\semplix{\tempsign}{1}#2}\else{}\fi\fi}}
```

You can see in the image below the results for the old version, your version and the new version of the macro[image: result of the 3 macros]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to increase the spacing between the minus sign and the number 142? It seems to me that the three versions of the macro behave in the same manner with respect to this. If one writes the expression as simply as $-2x^3+31 x^2-142 x +176$ the result is much better.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not easy. A result better than the one obtained with the new definition of the `\FPsignpol` macro requires a redefinition of other macros such as `\sempli`. We will think about it, nevertheless.

Comment: I see, thank you.